# Bootstrap 4 image grid alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, bootstrap-4

So I am creating an image grid using bootstrap 4.All the grid is included in the class "showcase".There are 2 landscape photos on the first row, and 3 portrait photos in the 2nd row.The problem is, I want the portrait photos to be aligned with the landscape photos.1 to the left, 1 in the center, and 1 to the right.I want them to have the same margin so it looks nice.

I tried googling and setting margins on my own.I tried using "row-sm-4" and stuff like that.

```
<div class = "showcase">
              <!-- First row with 2 landscape wallpapers -->
              <div class = "row" id = "land">
                <div class = "col">
                      <img src="img/land1.jpg" class="rounded float-left" alt = "Landscape wallpaper" width = "500" height = "350">
                      <img src="img/land2.jpg" class="rounded float-right" alt = "Landscape wallpaper" width = "500" height = "350">
              </div>
            </div>
              <!-- Second row with 3 portrait wallpapers-->
              <div class = "row" id = "port">
                <div class = "col-bg-4">
                  <img src="img/p1.jpeg" class="rounded float-left" id = "firstp" alt = "Portrait wallpaper" width = "200" height = "350">
                  <img src="img/p2.jpg" class="float-center" id = "secondp" alt = "Portrait wallpaper" width = "200" height = "350"> 
                  <img src="img/p3.jpg" class="rounded float-right" alt = "Portrait wallpaper" width = "200" height = "350">  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

It should show all the photos by the same left and right margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I fully understand what you mean then I think what you need to do is put the images into the correct amount of columns. For example:

Your 2 landscape images need to go into two columns with a span of 6.

Your 4 portrait images need to into 3 columns with a span of 4.

This should look something like this:

```
           <div class = "showcase">
              <!-- First row with 2 landscape wallpapers -->
              <div class = "row" id = "land">
                <div class = "col-6">
                      <img src="img/land1.jpg" class="rounded" alt = "Landscape wallpaper" width = "500" height = "350">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                      <img src="img/land2.jpg" class="rounded" alt = "Landscape wallpaper" width = "500" height = "350"> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
              <!-- Second row with 3 portrait wallpapers-->
              <div class = "row" id = "port">
                  <div class="col-4">                  
                      <img src="img/p1.jpeg" class="rounded" id = "firstp" alt = "Portrait wallpaper" width = "200" height = "350">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 text-center">                  
                      <img src="img/p2.jpg" class="" id = "secondp" alt = "Portrait wallpaper" width = "200" height = "350"> 
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-4">
                       <img src="img/p3.jpg" class="rounded" alt = "Portrait wallpaper" width = "200" height = "350">
                  </div>  
              </div>
          </div>
```

Let me know how it goes! You also won't need the `float`s

Comment: You understood correctly.The thing is that for the right hand side, it worked.But the distance from the center photo to the left photo is bigger than the distance from the center photo to the right photo, which makes it so it doesnt fix for the left hand side.

Comment: In that case add text-center to the div that you want to center. That should fix it for you!

Comment: wow it worked.At first, it didn't do anything because I didn't use the col-4 layout.I used css for it.Then I copied your code, which made it how I said above.When I said text-align center, it didnt do anything, but I just had to remove the css.Thank you! Tried to fix this for hours.

Comment: Glad I could help!